# Objc How to identify unique keys in an an array of objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I've been stumbling with this for a long while..

I have a large array of objects:

Name
Address
City
Phone

I want to get unique names.

But I need all objects for a specific name. (Name, Address, City, etc

I've tried using this:

`NSMutableArray *uniqueNameArray = [tempArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];`

But that leaves me with only "name" objects.

I could use some help please. If this has been answered already, please point me to that answer (I looked),and I will delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's better to use NSDictionary instead of NSArray?
key = uniq name; value = full object

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.